# Why is AWS Lambda handler invoked directly by some AWS while Lambda needs to poll others?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Why are some Amazon Web Services configured such that they can make direct calls to Lambda handlers with appropriate permissions, while for others like SQS, lambda needs to poll repeatedly? Why can't we have a provision for invoking Lambda as soon as a message is added to an SQS, instead of polling repeatedly?

Comment: AWS Lambda takes care of the polling for you. It is unlikely to introduce a delay. Are you experiencing a particular problem?

Comment: I'm not facing an issue. I want to understand the reason for the design. Why in some particular cases, we have polling, when sqs can directly handle calling the handler method once it receives a message? Isn't repeated polling causing us to have additional infrastructure and hence extra cost. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to scaling.

From [Understanding Scaling Behavior - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html):

> **Poll-based event sources that are not stream-based:** For Lambda functions that process Amazon SQS queues, AWS Lambda will automatically scale the polling on the queue until the maximum concurrency level is reached, where each message batch can be considered a single concurrent unit. AWS Lambda's automatic scaling behavior is designed to keep polling costs low when a queue is empty while simultaneously enabling you to achieve high throughput when the queue is being used heavily.
>
> When an Amazon SQS event source mapping is initially enabled, Lambda begins long-polling the Amazon SQS queue. Long polling helps reduce the cost of polling Amazon Simple Queue Service by reducing the number of empty responses, while providing optimal processing latency when messages arrive.
>
> When messages are available, Lambda initially launches up to 5 instances of your function, to handle 5 batches simultaneously. Then, Lambda launches up to 60 more instances per minute, up to 1000 total, as long as you have concurrency available at the account and function level.